# How to save variables and main program in some files and function to process variables in another files

Tags: python-2.7, function, global-variables, nameerror

so I try make program just like what I say in tittle with main program

`MainProgram.py`

```
data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
import Sub as sub
sub.aaa()
```

`Sub.py`

```
from MainProgram import data
newdata = data
def aaa():
   print len(newdata)
def bbb():
   print sum(newdata)
```

and when I run the Main Program it gives error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cheraldi/Desktop/Maha Besar Belajar Python dan Antek-anteknya/Calling Another Program/MainProgram.py", line 3, in 
    import Sub as sub
  File "C:/Users/Cheraldi/Desktop/Maha Besar Belajar Python dan Antek-anteknya/Calling Another Program\Sub.py", line 2, in 
    from MainProgram import data
  File "C:/Users/Cheraldi/Desktop/Maha Besar Belajar Python dan Antek-anteknya/Calling Another Program\MainProgram.py", line 5, in 
    aaa()
NameError: name 'aaa' is not defined

can someone help me? I read in some article to make "data" in mainprogram to global but it gave the same error

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward.  Nowhere do you define what `aaa` is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copy the wrong files. edited